# How to create an append function

Tags: scala, function, append

I am trying to create this function on scala but I am not quite sure if my way of doing is right. I think I am completely lost in this. I need help.

The function append(alist1, alist2), where alist1 and alist2 are two list-like collections of the same type.

The result should be a new list-like collection (with the same type as alist1 and alist2 ) that has the elements of alist1 followed by the
    elements of alist2 in order.
    i.e., on linked lists, append(alist1, alist2 ) should behave in a manner simlar to
    alist1 ++ alist2.

This is what I have so far

```
            def append [B :> A ]( alist1 : ListLike [B], alist2:ListLike[B]): ListLike [B] = (alist1,alist2) match {
case Nil => Nil
case hd1::tl1 = > hd1 :: tl1.append ( alist1) 
case hd2 ::tl2 => hd2 :: tl2.append(alist2)
        }
```

This is in SCALA.

Comment: What's `foldRight`? You implemented it?

Comment: What is `x`? What is used for?

Comment: Wow. Last edit was completely surprising

Comment: @Odomontois what does that mean?

Comment: @user_123945839432 I mean `BinTree` was totally unexpected here. 
You should specify more about your problem.I.e. if you have abstract type `ListLike` in which terms you would like to implement such operation, you probably should provide its definition in question

Comment: ok. I see... I'll make sure it's done.

Comment: Does `ListLike` have any constructor one could use?

Comment: It's inside a package I don't have access to. Here's the whole code I have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So imagine you have some scala-collection style abstract trait with base operations like *prepend*, *foldLeft* and *empty collection of same type*. It's pretty trivial to define `reverse` and `append` basing on them :

```
trait ListLike[+E, T[+X] <: ListLike[X, T]] {
  def +:[E1 >: E](x: E1): T[E1]

  def foldLeft[X](z: X)(f: (X, E) => X): X

  def empty: T[E]

  def reverse: T[E] = foldLeft(empty)((list, x) => x +: list)

  def ++[E1 >: E](that: T[E1]): T[E1] = reverse.foldLeft(that)((list, x) => x +: list)
}
```

Lets introduce some concrete type

```
sealed trait MyList[+E] extends ListLike[E, MyList] {
  def +:[E1 >: E](x: E1): MyList[E1] = MyCons(x, this)

  def empty = MyNil

  def foldLeft[X](z: X)(f: (X, E) => X): X = {
    def go(z: X, lst: MyList[E]): X = lst match {
      case MyNil => z
      case MyCons(x, next) => go(f(z, x), next)
    }
    go(z, this)
  }

  override def toString = foldLeft("MyList(")( _ + _ + ",") + ")"
}

case object MyNil extends MyList[Nothing]

case class MyCons[+E](elem: E, next: MyList[E]) extends MyList[E]
```

You can verify now that

```
(1 +: 2 +: 3 +: MyNil) ++ (4 +: 5 +: MyNil)
```

yields exact same thing (of same type) as

```
1 +: 2 +: 3 +: 4 +: 5 +: MyNil
```

**UPDATE**:
If you can't modify your abstract type you still can add move operations to some implicit wrapper preserving the syntax:

```
implicit class ListLikeOps[E, T[+X] <: ListLike[X, T] ](lst: ListLike[E, T]){
  def ++[E1 >: E](that: T[E1]): T[E1] = lst.reverse.foldLeft(that)((list, x) => x +: list)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared some methods(isEmpty, cons, head, tail) on a structure, using them I would write smth like:

```
trait Appendable[A]{
  def head: A = ???
  def tail: Appendable[A] = ???
  def isEmpty: Boolean = ???
  def reverse: Appendable[A] = ???
}

object Appendable{
  def cons[A](a: A, appendable: Appendable[A]): Appendable[A] = ???

  def append[A](a1: Appendable[A], a2: Appendable[A]) = 
    appendHelper(a1.reverse, a2)

  private def appendHelper[A](a1: Appendable[A], a2: Appendable[A]): Appendable[A] =
    if(a1.isEmpty) a2
    else appendHelper(a1.tail, cons(a1.head, a2))
}
```